# Missing Drawing in a 10 year old patent application

Tags: patent-infringment, de10353118

Why are the patent drawings not shown on the Google Patents page for this dismissed patent application DE 10353118 A1?

Do missing drawings provide for infringement on other patents?

Answer (score 1):

There are no drawings "missing" from this patent document at google patents. Only in the case of U.S. patent documents are drawings and a PDF of the original document provided at all. They aren't missing, they just aren't directly shown at google patents for any non-U.S. patent document.

For non-U.S. documents google provides a link to a location that has the definitive information. In this case, both a link to the German patent office and to the European patent office are included at the bottom of the gray box on the upper right.  At Espacenet (database for the EPO) the drawings are:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google is not an authoritative source for patent information -- It is only an convenient copy, which may at some time be out of date or incomplete.  For the authoritative patent, you should look up the patent in the appropriate country specific database -- in this case the German Patent database.

Looking at the notes in the google version of the patent it looks like it was rejected on Jun 16, 2011 -- not sure if that help you with your query regarding infringement.

Comment: Your answer is correct in case the DE data base is not corrupt or totally trustful, otherwise, publication on Google is so essential to determine the truth, because   Google as a third party has no interest in publication of false information. In last case the absence of drawings might happened because of a request of people who will get uncovered because of such untrue publication.

Comment: Very off track.